# Creating generic MongoDb helper class in C# 4.0

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to create a helper class for interacting with MongoDb in C# 4.0. I've been reading some of the documentation on serializing to Bson, etc. but am a little lost. What I have is a generic MongoHelper class with and Add(T objectToAdd), Delete(T objectToDelete) and  Update(T objectToUpdate) method. The constructor takes in the server, db and collection info.

I am having trouble however, trying to serialize from T. I ignorantly tried something like this:

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap().ToBsonDocument();

I'm really lost on such a simple thing. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to serialize your objects. The driver does that for you. If you are working with C# classes just make sure your class has a public no-argument constructor and that the values you want serialized are exposed as public properties. Classes like that are handled automatically. Alternatively, you might choose to work at a lower level with BsonDocuments, but they also are serialized for you automatically.

All you need to do to save an object of class C to the database is:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost/?safe=true");
var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<C>("test");
var c = new C();
// initialize c
collection.Insert(c);
```

That's all there is to it. To read it back you just write:

```
c = collection.FindOne();
```

although typically you would write a query as well.

Comment: Wow! So much easier! Using generics adds a bit of complexity but still way easier than SQL server. Thank you!

Comment: Actually you can use MongoDB.Dynamic to abstract you MongoDB Collections and use it as you helper class. http://www.assembla.com/spaces/mongodb-dynamic/wiki